# Extract name of website from an absolute URL

Tags: code-golf

You will take input such as

http://examples.example.co.nz/abcdefg

and return the name of the website, in which this example would be `example`.

To be more specific, I am looking for the [Second Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain), which immediately precedes the TLD (Top Level Domain), but the Third Level Domain if the website is a [Country Code Second-Level Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_second-level_domain).

Shortest bytes wins (competition ends March the 5th)!

Comment: Wouldn't it be `examples.example.com`?

Comment: @Strigoides Let me make it more specific

Comment: What would the expected result be for `http://foo.bar.co.nz`?

Comment: @Strigoides Uh... bar, I guess..?

Comment: Edited to make it more clear what you are looking for. Still, the end result of this approach to getting the site name is going to be pretty poor in many cases. Del.icio.us, Blo.gs, Instagr.am. Even stats.stackexchange.com, in which the third-level domain is the most significant identifier, but even then it is not the title of the site, which is Cross Validated.

Comment: In your example, the SLD is `co`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Jonathan edited that in, I wasn't the one who confused you.  I've edited it now so it's more specific.

Comment: Aha. The question could still use improvement: firstly to define an authoritative source on which SLDs are ccSLDs, and secondly to define behaviour when the input isn't in that exact format (e.g. may we assume that the URL is always http? May we assume that it's an absolute URL? May we assume that the domain is never a TLD? May we assume that it never includes a username, password, or port number component?

Comment: @PeterTaylor ^That's exactly the exact... yes, okay, adding to answer

Comment: I've reviewed this question 4 times! enough closing and reopening!

Comment: I don't think the edits address any of my five requests for clarification.

Comment: Sounds like this could have used some time in the Sandbox... where we could have buried it with the proper rites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ruby, 15 characters

Assuming input is stored in variable `s`.

```
s.split(?.)[-2]
```

## GolfScript, 7

Exact translation.

```
"."/-2=
```

## Ruby with edge cases, 28

Such as `http://example.com/foo.bar`

```
s.split(?/)[2].split(?.)[-2]
```

## GolfScript with edge cases, 13

```
"/"/2="."/-2=
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the case I asked about (a url containing a ccSLD). Not sure how you're supposed to distinguish between, say `foo.co.nz` (foo) and `subdomain.co.com` (co) though. The question seems a little underspecified.

Comment: I'm not even gonna try. Golfscript and co just ruin all the fun

Comment: @TheDoc That's no reason to downvote. Should I downvote all Java answers just because I don't like that language? You're still free to answer in whatever language you want; there's nothing stopping you.

Comment: @Doorknob But it means that me and my python will never win

Comment: @TheDoc That's pretty bad sportsmanship, downvoting all answers that beat yours. There's notHing stopping you from answering in Python.

Comment: @TheDoc Please do not vote on the *language* used in a post...

Comment: @Doorknob Unless the post is full of foul *language*. ;-)

Comment: @Doorknob - well, you downvoted me for disallowing Golfscript

Comment: @TheDoc Yes, I downvote posts that have arbitrary and unnecessary restrictions. There is absolutely no reason to disallow a language.

Comment: @TheDoctor You know, me and my C++, Java, and Python 3 have never one either.

Comment: @TheDoctor I've never won with my knowledge of GolfScript, CJam, and Pyth. (Not that I know much Pyth)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 27 bytes

Assuming `a` is the variable and `c` is a 1 or 0,

```
i=a.split('.')[i.length-c];
```

would work.  `c` is set to 3 if the domain is a `ccsld` and set to 2 if the domain isn't a `ccsld`.  `c` can also be edited to a larger number if the page has dots in it.

Comment: Uhhh, `x==false?y:z` is the exact same as `x?z:y`.

Comment: Ummm, I'm not sure what you're saying...

Comment: ...when did I say that? Read my comments carefully...

Comment: @Doorknob Oh, yes... :)

Comment: What about `i[i.length-ccsld-2]`?

Comment: You could combine all three lines into `i=a.split(".")[i.length-c];`

Answer (score 3):

## C, 120

```c
char s[999],*p,*q,*r;main(){gets(s);for(q=p=strstr(s,"//")+2,*strstr(p,"/")=0;*p;p++)if(*p=='.')*p=0,r=q,q=p+1;puts(r);}
```

Answer (score 2):

The 2 "solutions' above fail, what if the website has the URL www.some1.name.ext/whatever.this/www/?

The solution in JavaScript is:

```
var arr = myurl.split('/');
var domain = arr[2];
var arr2 = domain.split('.');
var name = arr2[arr2.length-2];
```

or

```
name = myurl.split('/')[2].split('.')[myurl.split('/')[2].split('.').length-2];
```

Comment: Please golf your code and state the length (remove redundant space, use one-letter variable names...).

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 30

Python's not too good for these things.

```
a.split("/")[2].split(".")[-2]
```

Doesn't work for TLDs with more than one `.`.

Comment: This doesn't work with the listed example - returns 'co' instead of 'example'.

Comment: @user17752 Ah - I guess it only works for general TLDs with one `.`. Since there can be an arbitrary number of `.`s in a URL, how can this work? Especially with the new custom TLDs?

Answer (score 1):

## Python2 172, Python3 156

This one is long, but i think it fullfills all the requeriments of the question.

```
s = "http://examples.example.co.nz/abcdefg"

#BEGIN_CODE
import re,urllib2
l=re.findall("..",urllib2.urlopen("http://goo.gl/molpki").read())
m=re.search(r"(?:\w+\.)*(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)",s)
g=m.groups()
r=g[0]if g[2]in l else g[1]
#END_CODE

print(r)
```

`l` contains a list of all country codes from wikipedia
`m` contains the last third, second and first level domains, dropping all the others
`r` contains the result

All could go in a line, but since `;` is the same as `\n` i leave it like this.

EDIT:
Tested with `www.some1.name.ext/whatever.this/www/?` and returns `name` so i guess it works.

#### Python 3 version

```
import re,requests as u
g=re.search(r"(?:\w+\.)*(\w+)"+"\.(\w+)"*2,s).groups()
r=g[0]if g[2]in re.findall("..",u.get("http://goo.gl/molpki").text) else g[1]
```

Same as above, r contains result.